# Unable to plot all variables of a dataset Seaborn heat map

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, data-science

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.heatmap(df.corr())
```

The data has 14 variables but only the first 4 are plotted on heat map. Is it related to missing values in the remaining variables?

Comment: Check data type of all your columns.

Comment: Yes some of them are string varibales but most of them are numeric. Also do you know how to deal with values which are just blank, I mean no Nan or anything just blank '  '. Does that affect heatmap?

Comment: @DhrumilVaishnav can you provide examples of your data?

Comment: `pd.to_numeric` on all string columns `errors='coerce'`

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken, unless your string values are categorical (check for `python to_categorical` which means new columns for each string of 0s and 1s), you can't correlate them using `.corr()`, as you're mentioning at second code line `sns.heatmap(df.corr())`. Meaning there will be less features (variables) to make your heatmap.

Check these examples:

```
# first import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Will return empty, having strings:

```
values = np.transpose([[3,'dos',9], ['cuatro',9, 7], [4,5,6], [4,5,6]])
cols = ["first", 'second','third','fourth']
print(pd.DataFrame(values, columns=cols).corr())
```

Will achieve what you need:

```
# only numbers for the values
values = np.transpose([[1,3,9], [10,20, 7], [4,5,6], [4,5,6]])
cols = ["first", 'second','third','fourth']
print(pd.DataFrame(values, columns=cols).corr())
```